# How to deal with a manager who lies and hides information?

Tags: management, colleagues, manager, politics, layoff

I work for a very large company in USA. Some of us are allowed to work remotely sometimes or always. A few months after starting my job, I saw evidence that my manager praised me in front of me, but was secretly critical of me. So, I asked him for feedback about my nature, skills and work ethic. But he only praised me instead of giving me genuine feedback. Anyway, I still continued the job for "good" reasons.

Some of my teammates are poor performers and often shirked their responsibilities. I provided my manager with the evidence. It appears that he scolded them, because they became more responsible after my private complaints. But, they still remained poor performers. I had to help them out with basic stuff in their work and fix their mistakes. But, it seems that no real corrective action was taken against them.

A few years later, our company announced mass layoffs and also some new projects which received more funding. My manager quietly moved one high performing teammate to a new project without informing the team. We only discovered after I asked the manager about the absence of the teammate in a team meeting. Later, the manager moved one of the poor performers to a new project and a high performer to an unspecified project. But, he at least informed the team about it this time. He has given the remaining team some work to do, but it seems to be of poor quality. To give you an analogy, my manager has knowingly/unknowingly given us a bad foundation and asked us to build a house on it.

What do I do ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your role in the team? Are you the team leader? Who is in charge of assigning work in the team?

Comment: Also, I'm honestly confused by the mention of working from home, and the distinction between poor and high performers. Does this detail matter?

Comment: "What do I do?" This cannot be answered unless you let us know what you want to achieve as an outcome.

Answer (score 3):

> I saw evidence that my manager praised me in front of me, but was secretly critical of me

There are a few different reasons why this occur. They could be trying to ensure you don't lose confidence, think you're argumentative and don't want to argue with you, don't want to initiate performance improvement plans, trying to downplay your worth so you don't get transferred out, etc. It's really hard to say without more context. But it happened at least a few years ago.

> But, it seems that no real corrective action was taken against them.

You said you manager scolded them, it had some sort of effect, but it wasn't enough. How is he lying or withholding information?

> My manager quietly moved one high performing teammate to a new project without informing the team.

It would be polite to inform the team, but he certainly don't have to. During restructuring / mass-layoffs there is a lot of things going on. It could have been a simple oversight.

The exception is if you are in a leadership position and you need to know this information in order to plan the work.

**How to deal with a manager who lies and hides information?**

To be honest, through all your text, it appears there is only one action over the course of at least a few years, where he has withheld information from you, and in that instance could have been just a simple oversight.

I think you have grievances around the movement of employees in the business and the composition of the team you are in, and you're trying to justify those grievances by suggesting your boss is chronically deceptive. If this is not true, you should (heavily) modify you question to cull out useless detail. If it is true, you should retitle your question.